# What is procedure to calculate physical memory address?

Tags: memory

How can we calculate the physical memory address generated by the following segment:offset pairs (both are hexadecimal values).

1. `0010:0200`
2. `0100:DFAD`
3. `DADD:6727`

Answer (score 1):

```
address = segment << 4 + offset
```

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Segmentation) for details.